# Failed to connect to MySQL: Unknown database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on php at the moment and I am having problem with connecting to a server data base I am using MAMP 
this is my code

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','something');

// Check connection 
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 else
 {
   echo "string";
   }
  ?>
```

[image: I did create my data base in my php admin as it's shown in the pic]

[image: 2]

I really hope you help me in my learning process

this is the error massage I got 
Failed to connect to MySQL: Unknown database 'something'

Comment: You creating database at `demo.phpmyadmin.net` and your host is `localhost`? are you sure you are in `demo.phpmyadmin.net` host?

Comment: No I am not sure , how can I make sure of that ?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the database you've created in an online demo of the PhpMyAdmin program? I'm pretty sure they've secured their system to make that impossible.

Comment: check out these video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8TP2FERKls&t=697shttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8TP2FERKls&t=697s) and so much other all working on demo

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your password is "root"?  If you're using WAMP (as suggested by localhost), the default password for `mysql` is "" (blank).

Comment: yes my dear friend I am sure the problem to me seems at connecting or finding the table name .. please check the error massage I just add at might help you to help me , if not thank you for trying .

Answer (score 0):

I think you have changed the `localhost` name as `demo`..and by default localhost username and password is `root` and ``(no-passsword)..So just try it..

`$con = mysqli_connect('demo','root','','something');`